# TextView height does not match_parent / fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview, fill-parent

I have a simple TextView with a singleLine.
I would like to set the height to match_parent/fill_parent, but the behaviour of Android is to only to wrap_content.

Is there a way to force that the TextView takes all height ?

Tkx

Edit :

This is what I get :

[image]
and my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="13dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        [...]

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have same issue, did you end up with something else or solved with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For that `TextView` parent width, you may use `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **TextView** height to **match_parent/fill_parent**. And change the **gravity** and **all other property** of that **TextView** according to your requirement.

If this is not suffiecient for you then let me know what exactly you want to do.

**EDIT:**

As per your new edited code i worked on your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/date" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp" 
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:text="dateText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now its showing the **TextView** at the **central_vertical** position of the whole screen.

Try this code. Its working. Change your **RelativeLayout** and **TextView** as i did with these.